# JSON file importing keys saving as objects instead of number values in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I am working with MongoDB and whenever I import the values as a JSON file it ends up saving the CustNo. and OrderNo. as an object instead of a number. I am thinking it has something to do with the "." in the key. How can I avoid saving these values as an object when they should be a number?

```
{
"OrderNo.": 2000,
"Order Date": "26/05/2022",
"CustNo.": 233222232,
"Product Code": 1,
"Product Type": "Olive oil",
"Product Quantity": 11,
"Price": 90,
"Total": 232,
"ModeOf Payment": "Cash"
}
```

The current result ends up being

```
OrderNo: Object
       : 2000
```

If I import as text it works without a problem but I am required to use JSON.

Comment: Would you show how you are importing the JSON file?

Comment: Additionally, would it be possible to modify the name of the fields in the source file/program?

Comment: Using either MongoDB Compass to import a JSON file to a collection or by using Postman using a JSON post request

Comment: I just tried importing with MongoDB Compass and I see the problem. Reading [MongoDB Warnings about field names with `.`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#general-restrictions), I think I would avoid that at almost any cost.  You could do it, but if you do, you should expect plenty of future query/update/import pain.